# Is there a way to view/access your computer over the network in boot mode

Tags: networking

For systems with no IPMI or such built in, is there a way to access them over the network to do work and access boot options?

If I am out and I have a machine doing a check disk, would there be a way to send the screen and controls over the network?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a external piece of hardware called a [IP-KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28IPKVM.29). You will commonly find this built in to enterprise class servers but you can get it as [separate hardware too](https://www.google.com/search?q=IP%20KVM&tbm=shop) (expect to pay $400-$900 depending on the number of devices it can connect to and features).

What this does is act as a 3rd computer on the network that can forward keyboard, video, and mouse signals between the computer you are interested in and the machine you are connecting from via some kind of web interface (often Java or ActiveX powered)